# Searching filename for certain string and saving it to a variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let's say I have files with a very specific naming scheme. For instance, maybe I have a file named `x=1,y=15,z=63.txt`, and I've saved this filename to the variable `file`. I want to search the variable for the string `"x="`, and then save the number after that to a variable `x`. Likewise for `y` and `z`.

```
x="search x=*, $file"
y="search y=*, $file"
z="search z=*.txt $file"
```

As a shell script newbie, these are obviously fake commands and this won't compile, but I hope it outlines my goal. Any solution for what I am trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand, is `"x=1,y=15,z=63.txt"` _contents_ of file1?

Comment: No, it's the name of the file. I've edited the post for clarity.

Comment: So just to be clear, you want to create the variables $x, $y and $z according to the way they appear in the name of the file?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: should the `.txt`  extension should be part of $z?

Comment: No, I would like "x" to be equal to 1, "y" to be equal to 15, and "z" to be equal to 63.

Comment: What's the relevance of the word `search`, and what do you want to say with the three lines of assignments in the middle of your question?

Comment: Search is a hypothetical fake command. What I want to say in words is "search the variable $file for the string "x=", followed by something, followed by ",". Save that "something" to a variable $x.

Answer (score 3):

Note: The answer works for `bash` shell, and assumes there are no special characters in the name of the file such as spaces.

Assuming the `$file` variable contains the name of the file, first you need to remove the suffix of the file:

```
$ file=${file%.*}
$ echo $file
x=1,y=15,z=63
```

Now `$file` would be only `x=1,y=15,z=63`.

Now you can use the `declare` builtin in `bash`:

```
declare ${file//,/ }
```

`${file//,/ }` would replace all the comma characters to spaces, so this would be expanded by bash to:

```
declare x=1 y=15 z=63
```

And the result would be:

```
$ declare ${file//,/ }
$ echo $x $y $z
1 15 63
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with sed to pull out the numbers.

```
$ echo x=1,y=15,z=63  | sed 's/.*x=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
1
$ echo x=1,y=15,z=63  | sed 's/.*y=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
15
$ echo x=1,y=15,z=63  | sed 's/.*z=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
63
```

Comment: What if the value of `x` were `x123foo`? If this is a `,`-delimited set of key/value pairs, you would want to use something like `sed 's/.*x=\([^,]\+\).*/\1/'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are integers, regular expression matching would be a concise way to extract the values.

This is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```bash
file='x=1,y=15,z=63.txt'

if [[ $file =~ "x="([0-9]+)",y="([0-9]+)",z="([0-9]+) ]]; then
    x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    y=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    z=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi

declare -p x y z
```

output

```
declare -- x="1"
declare -- y="15"
declare -- z="63"
```

Comment: Why limit to integers? You're using regexes, might as well go for `$file =~ "x="([^,]+)",y="([[^,]+)",z="([^,]+) `